# How to set values in an OpenCV 64FC1 matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am trying to make a matrix of three rows and one column with the values 1, 2 and 3 in it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    cv::Mat point = cv::Mat::ones(3, 1, CV_64FC1);
    point.at<double>(1,1) = 1.0d;
    point.at<double>(1,2) = 2.0d;
    point.at<double>(1,3) = 3.0d;
    std::cout << point << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
[1
 1
 1]
```

And the expected output is:

```
[1
 2
 3]
```

How are values set in an OpenCV matrix?

Comment: btw, after seeing the name you've given to your mat, for many opertions you can use `cv::Point3d` to get an object with 3 double values and has some functionality like scalar multiplication, addition etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are accessing the wrong element. The correct way is:

```
cv::Mat point = cv::Mat(3, 1, CV_64FC1);
point.at<double>(0,0) = 1.0d;
point.at<double>(1,0) = 2.0d;
point.at<double>(2,0) = 3.0d;
```

Simpler than that:

```
double data[3] = {1.0d, 2.0d, 3.0d};
cv::Mat point = cv::Mat(3, 1, CV_64FC1, &data);
```

Comment: indexing is still wrong. `cv::Mat(3, 1, CV_64FC1);` means 3 rows, 1 col, so it must be `point.at<double>(0,0) = 1.0d;` `point.at<double>(1,0) = 2.0d;` `point.at<double>(2,0) = 3.0d;` to really be correct.

Comment: Of course that is wrong, thanks for your correction.
I trusted that part of @Tom implementation. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

As @zedv says, you have to access the matrix elements with 0-based indices.

Another way to create a matrix with known values is this:

```
cv::Mat point = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,1) << 1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is from [OpenCv Forum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/45935/interfaces-stdvector-to-cvmat/), where the solution could be:

```
std::vector<cv::Point3d> test;
test.push_back(cv::Point3d(0, 1, 2)); 
test.push_back(cv::Point3d(3, 4, 5));
cv::Mat cvt(test, false);//second param for data copy (here, data are not duplicated!)
```

Which is quite nifty :)